# Installing Windows programs and Lexmark X4650 printer

Tags: drivers, windows, wine, lexmark

I am using Ubuntu 12.04. What software do I need to so I can install Windows programs from CD or flash drive? Is this software in the Ubuntu Software Center or do I download it from a website? At one point I saw a program called Wine for running Windows applications in Ubuntu?

Currently the CD/DVD drive isn't recognized. Also how can I install and use my Lexmark all-in-one printer? The Lexmark website doesn't list Ubuntu 12.04 for downloadable drivers.

I hope my Windows programs are not all garbage because I have Ubuntu and Windows 7 has been deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the driver for your Lexmark printer, download and follow instructions:

http://support.lexmark.com/index?productCode=LEXMARK_X4650&segment=DOWNLOAD&os=UBUNTU_9.10&oslocale=en_US&page=content&actp=DD_LIST&id=DR20523&locale=EN&userlocale=EN_UK

Comment: When I go to the link and click download I get a message: We're sorry for the inconvenience. There was an error with the application. Also, during a live Lexmark chat, I was told Lexmark doesn't have a driver and that I'd have to buy a new Lexmark printer.  Am I running 32 or 64 bit? When I had Windows 7 it was 64 bit.  That Lexmark link seems to be 32 bit.

Comment: When I go to the link and click download I get a message: We're sorry for the inconvenience. There was an error with the application. Also, during a live Lexmark chat, I was told Lexmark doesn't have a driver and that I'd have to buy a new Lexmark printer. Am I running 32 or 64 bit? When I had Windows 7 it was 64 bit. That Lexmark link seems to be 32 bit

Comment: Lexmark seems notorious for having bad linux support, when a driver is available it seems to disappear after a while...  Sorry I can't be or more help dude...  If possible stick with HP printers for linux...

Answer (score 0):

About running windows software in linux(ubuntu):

To run the windows software on ubuntu, you need to download and install wine. It is available in ubuntu software center. If you want to run windows programs which don't need installation, it will be enough for you. But, if you want to install windows programs, although it is possible to do this with wine, I strongly recommend you install playonlinux. It is a front-end for wine. It is also available in software center, and if you install it, it will automatically install wine, so you don't have to worry about installing them both. It is important that you enter **playonlinux** and not **play on lnux**, as it will not find it in the search if you enter it with spaces. If you want to install games or some other more advanced windows programs, you'll need to install additional components. Note that playonlinux has a list of components needed for some programs, so it can install the components and programs automatically.